# Why the mouse doesn't move in mouse-look feature of RPG/FPS games?

Tags: c++, rpg, windows, first-person-shooter

### Description

The mouse look (or [free look](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_look), i.e., move the mouse to change the view/camera) is common in RPG and FPS games. In my cloud game project, I tried to achieve this feature. Before programming, I tested an RPG game (Genshin) in Windows, I started it directly in my PC and used spy++ to check what happened when I moved the mouse. I got these results:

[image]

It seemed that however I moved the mouse, although the role's view changed, the positions in WM_MOUSEMOVE messages didn't change too much. Actually, 640 and 343 were about the half of the resolution sizes (1280*720).

### Question

How those games achieve this: move the mouse and change the role's view, but the positions in messages don't change? What bottom winapis are used?
(I hooked `ClipCursor` and the input parameters of [ClipCursor](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-clipcursor) were just my screen's width and height.) In cloud games, I need to use remote mice (clients' inputs) to achieve this feature, what can I do?

Answer (score 2):

> How those games achieve this: move the mouse and change the role's view, but the positions in messages don't change?

See the `WM_SETCURSOR` messages immediately following the `WM_MOUSEMOVE` ones?
That's how!

They will always reset the mouse cursor to the center of the viewport, i.e.
`SetCursorPos(iViewportWidth / 2, iViewportHeight / 2)`.

In your case that would be `SetCursorPos(640,360)` - c.f. [SetCursorPos](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setcursorpos)

The next time you move the mouse Windows sends the new cursor position in a `WM_MOUSEMOVE` message, like `(628, 363)` - and the program then calculates `(628 - 640, 363 - 360)`, which is `(-12,3)` and is the *relative* mouse movement (in respect of the last value). So it will then calculate the new camera view of looking more to the left (because `x = -12` is negative) and a little bit further down (`y = +3`). It then immediately resets the cursor position to the center via `SetCursorPos(640,360)` and the process repeats.

This way the mouse cursor will never reach the window borders and be clipped by Windows - which would lead to strange effects.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I still have some questions:
1. According to ms document, parameters for SetCursorPos should be "screen" coordinates. Should I use `ClientToScreen` to change `iViewportWidth / 2, iViewportHeight / 2` to screen coordinates?

Comment: 2. The whole procedure, according to your answer, is post WM_MOUSEMOVE-process this message-set the cursor to the center. In cloud game situations (client-server), the server side just has the inputs of the client. So I post the message and set the cursor, but how to process the message, i.e., get the relative mouse movement and change the camera view?

Comment: That sounds like a different question than the one you asked. "How do I implement camera movement in a client-server FPS" versus "Why the mouse doesn't move in mouse-look". You can create a new question post to explain your current situation in more detail and ask for help with the part you need.

Comment: @DMGregory Thanks for your advice.